# Having Trouble with this awk script

Tags: scripts, awk

I've tried invoking the script below with the line `awk 'filecount'`.  It should print out the file information and a line number, followed by the total number of files in the directory, but nothing happens.

What's wrong with this script?

```awk
#!/usr/bin/awk

BEGIN { 
    files=0;
}
{
    files++;
    print files, "\t", $9, "\n", $3, "\n\n";
}
END {
    print "Total Files:  ", files, "\n\n"
}
```

Comment: What information about the files do you want to print? I don't know `awk`, but probably there will be an alternative solution.

Comment: Where is it supposed to get this file information from? My *guess* is you want it to parse the output of an `ls -l` command. Also note that the shebang for an awk script needs to be followed by `-f` in order for it to read commands from the remainder of the file `#!/usr/bin/awk -f`

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I want to pipe output into it with ls -l.  And that shebang might help a lot.  I'll certainly try it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Issues with original script

There's a few problems with your script. First of all, the first line should be `#!/usr/bin/awk -f`. Second you said,

> It should print out the file information and a line number

but in  your script  this part counts line number instead of file count, which is also redundant , because AWK has `NR` and `FNR` variables that already do that:

```
{
    files++;
    print files, "\t", $9, "\n", $3, "\n\n";
}
```

---

#### Proper working approach

As far as I understand, your main requirement is to print line count in each file and print total processed files in current directory. This can be easily done with bash on command line:

```
$ counter=0; for file in * ; do [ -f "$file" ] && [ -r "$file"  ] &&  { wc -l "$file"; counter=$(($counter+1)); }; done ; echo "Total files:" "$counter"
45 center_active_window.py
41 get_terminal.py
91 typescript
1 xprop.txt
17 xrandr_script.py
Total files: 5
```

If you insist on doing this with awk , it's possible as well , but pay attention - all files in the directory should be regular text files and readable.

Below is the script and its sample run:

```
$ cat ~/filecount.awk                                                                                                    
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

FNR==1{

    if (FNR!=NR){
        print counter,last_file;
    }
    filecounter++;
    last_file=ARGV[ARGIND];
    counter=0
};

{counter++};

END{
    print last_file,counter;    
    print "Files processed: ", filecounter;
}

$ ~/filecount.awk *  2> /dev/null                                                                                        
45 center_active_window.py
41 get_terminal.py
91 typescript
1 xprop.txt
xrandr_script.py 17
Files processed:  5
```

The idea here is simple:

- every time line number in file ( the `FNR` variable ) is 1 , we record filename using ARGV array and ARGIND variable. We increment file counter, and set line number to 0;
- if the record number isn't the same as record number *in current file*, that means we've already processed at least one file, so we can print out the information about it. That's what the `if (FNR!=NR){ . . .` part does
- Essentially we're processing file, and then looking backwards at its info.
- Once we're through all files, we need to print information about last one (because remember, the script works by looking backwards at all items) , and then print the total file counter.